# Compare two arrays and print number of matching elements

Tags: c

Hello I am trying to create an array of 6 random numbers as my lottery numbers and compare them to my ticket to see how many matches I have. 
I am struggling with passing pointers as the functions arguments.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>


int *get_lotto_draw(int n)
    {
        int i;
        static int lotto[6];

        int lottery[50];
        int u,j,temp;

        for (i =0; i<49; i++)
            lottery[i] = i+1;


        for (i =0; i<49; i++)
        {
            j = (rand()%49)+1;

            temp = lottery[i];
            lottery[i] = lottery[j];
            lottery[j] = temp;
        }

            for (i =0; i<6; i++)    
            {
                lotto[i] = lottery[i];
            }

        return lotto;           
    }

find_matches(int *lotto, int *ticket)
    {       
        int arrayReturn[sizeof(lotto) + sizeof(ticket)];
        int count = 0;
        int i;
        int j;
        for(i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        {
            for(j = 0; j < 6; j++)
            {
                if(lotto[i]==lotto[j])
                {
                    count = count + 1;

                }
            }
        }

        return count;
    }   


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    int i, n = 6;
    int *lotto;
    int ticket[6] = {5, 11, 15, 33, 42, 43};

    srand(time(NULL));

    lotto = get_lotto_draw(n);

    int count = find_matches(&lotto[6], &ticket[6]);

    printf("%d\n\n", count);


    printf("Here is the array: ");
    for(i = 0 ; i < n ; i++) { 
        printf("%d ", lotto[i]); 
    }

    printf("\n\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is a Q/A site. Without the question, it is (in most cases) impossible to "answer" it

Comment: If you want someone to look are your code, please use sane and consistent indention and brace placement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code to do the comparison:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>


int *get_lotto_draw(int n)
{
    int i;
    static int lotto[6];

    int lottery[50];
    int j, temp;

    for (i = 0; i<49; i++)
        lottery[i] = i + 1;


    for (i = 0; i<49; i++){
        j = (rand() % 49) + 1;

        temp = lottery[i];
        lottery[i] = lottery[j];
        lottery[j] = temp;
    }

    for (i = 0; i<6; i++){
        lotto[i] = lottery[i];
    }

    return lotto;
}

int find_matches(int *lotto, int *ticket)
{
    int count = 0;
    int i;
    int j;
    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++){
        for (j = 0; j < 6; j++){
            if (lotto[i] == ticket[j]){
                count++;
            }
        }
    }

    return count;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i, n = 6;
    int *lotto;
    int ticket[6] = { 5, 11, 15, 33, 42, 43 };
    int count = 0;

    srand(time(NULL));

    lotto = get_lotto_draw(n);
    printf("\nHere is the lotto array: ");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%d ", lotto[i]);
    }
    printf("\nHere is the ticket array: ");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%d ", ticket[i]);
    }

    count = find_matches(lotto, ticket);

    printf("\ncount of matches: %d", count);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
int count = find_matches(&lotto[6], &ticket[6]);
```

you pass addresses of `lotto[6]` and `ticket[6]` which is an invalid array element. You actually wanted to write

```
int count = find_matches(lotto, ticket);
```

which is the same as

```
int count = find_matches(&lotto[0], &ticket[0]);
```

as array names "decays" to a pointer to its first element.

There are other problems too!

1. The function declaration:

   ```
   find_matches(int *lotto, int *ticket)
   ```

   is missing a return type. Fix it by using

   ```
   int find_matches(int *lotto, int *ticket)
   ```
2. The array declaration

   ```
   int arrayReturn[sizeof(lotto) + sizeof(ticket)];
   ```

   is wrong as `lotto` and `ticket` is an `int*`. So the `sizeof` operator returns the size of an `int*`, not the size of the entire array. You'll have to either hardcode the values or pass the size as an argument to the function.
3. In the function `get_lotto_draw`, I don't see any reason why `lottery` has 50 indices. You only need 6 of them. Anyway, the last (49<sup>th</sup>) index isn't used, too.

Answer (score 0):

Your invocation is incorrect, and it causes undefined behavior:

```
int count = find_matches(&lotto[6], &ticket[6]);
```

this passes pointers to one-past-end of both arrays, so `find_matches` would perform invalid dereference.

Proper way to call your function is as follows:

```
int count = find_matches(lotto, ticket);
```

or if you are set on using `&` operator,

```
int count = find_matches(&lotto[0], &ticket[0]);
```

Also note that this declaration

```
find_matches(int *lotto, int *ticket) ...
```

is pre-ANSI, because the return type of the function is omitted (in which case C compiler assumes `int`). You should change the declaration to supply the return type explicitly:

```
int find_matches(int *lotto, int *ticket) ...
```

Comment: @AliDavies You are welcome! If you are not looking for further help with this question, please consider accepting an answer by clicking the grey check mark next to it. This would let other site visitors know that your problem is solved, and earn you a new badge on Stack Overflow.